# HP Compaq Business Desktop dc7600 Small Form Factor Desktop PC - What's new in HP BIOS 786D1 v01.61 updated from 786D1 v01.03

Tags: bios

HP Compaq dc7600 Small Form Factor Desktop PC - What's new in HP BIOS 786D1 v01.61 (updating from 786D1 v01.03). Is it worth upgrading?

Will this BIOS upgrade expand the range of CPUs I could upgrade to? 
Will it overcome the "only able to see 3.2GB of 4GB RAM" problem?

Answer (score 2):

This BIOS version changelog can be found [here](ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp44001-44500/sp44223.html)

> ENHANCEMENTS:
>
> - Adds support for full-speed hubs with endpoint numbers greater than 1.
>
> FIXES:
>
> - Fixes an issue where the system stops responding (hangs) while Microsoft  Windows is loading when keys are pressed and multiple
>   keyboards are present.  The BIOS now checks USB UHCI controllers for
>   ownership changes or halt state  before attempting runtime device
>   enumeration.

In effect, nothing too substantial. Of course, there may be other BIOS versions in between yours and this one that may have addressed other issues.

It's unlikely the range of CPU's you can use is limited by the BIOS, more likely the chipset of the machine. The other issue you mention, only being able to see 3.2GB of 4GB RAM, is likely a combination of:

- Running a 32-bit operating system
- Having shared, integrated graphics

If you aren't having any problems with your machine, I wouldn't recommend doing the update, as BIOS updates *can* result in a machine that will no longer boot should anything go wrong, such as power loss.